# In SBT, how can I append to the classpath?

Tags: scala, sbt

I have Apache Spark located in a particular directory.  I want to add the directory in which Spark's jars are located to the search path for jar files that SBT uses.  How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
unmanagedJars in Compile += file("/path/to/jars")
```

This tells sbt to include that path to the jars to load in the classpath, in addition to the default `lib` directory.